# How to smartly convert a number of seconds in a date-time value using C

Tags: c, algorithm, date, time

In my embedded Linux application I have a "tick count" counter that increases 1 each 10 nanoseconds counting from 1st January 00:00:00 of 2014.

I want to be able to, picking the current value of the "tick count" counter, print it as the current date-time (year, month, day, hour, minute, second and millisecond) of my system already considering things such as leap year, February having 28/29 days, etc. and this using pure C methods (from time.h etc.).

But I don't know how to do it... For now I have the equivalent value in seconds, so I know how many seconds since the start date-time have passed, but not how to go from that to the current date-time value with everything adjusted, only in Qt which is not available (and the internet wasn't much of a help in this case till what could I understood of the explanations in cplusplus.com and etc.)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the latest date that must convert successfully?

Comment: Are you willing to assume the POSIX-specified representation for `time_t` of seconds since Epoch?

Comment: as a correction, February is either 28 or 29 days, not 27 or 28.

Comment: @user3629249 yeah, that's the problem of writing a question in a hurry :)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I'm not sure about the details of `time_t` that could be reasons for me not to accept it; I only know that I tried to use the methods from `time.h` and I was unsuccessful as well as that it considers the count of time since 1970, which is not my situation.

Comment: @chux any; The counter can go on till overflow (it's an unsigned 64 bit int, so it can go on for a long time even though that's not expected in practice).

Comment: Both of the answers so far assume the 1970 Epoch representation for `time_t`, which standard C does not require (but POSIX does).

Comment: @Momergil Note: 64-bit 10's of nanoseconds from 2014 goes to about year 7860.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `gmtime()`.

Simply divide the tick count to get the whole number of seconds and add an offset to change the epoch from Jan 1, 2014 to Jan 1, 1970.

```
void print_time(unsigned long long tick_count) {

  static const unsigned long ticks_per_sec = 100000000L;
  static const time_t epoch_delta = 16071L*24*60*60;
  time_t seconds = tick_count/ticks_per_sec + epoch_delta;

  unsigned long fraction = tick_count%ticks_per_sec;
  struct tm tm = *gmtime(&seconds);
  printf("%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03lu\n",
      tm.tm_year+1900, tm.tm_mon+1, tm.tm_mday,
      tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec,
      fraction/10000);
}
```

---

[After Accept Edit]

OP comments "I tried to use the methods from time.h and I was unsuccessful as well as that it considers the count of time since 1970, which is not my situation"

Another approach is to use `mktime()`.  This is less dependent on issues brought up by @DavidEisenstat.  It relies on the `tm_sec` field being an `int` of sufficient width (like 32 bits) to cover years 2014 to 2082.  `mktime()` takes out-of-range fields and adjusts them to the expected ranges.  Should `tm_sec` be 16-bit, some simple adjustments could be had to `tm_mday, tm_hour, tm_min, tm_sec` instead.

```
void print_time2(unsigned long long tick_count) {

  static const unsigned long ticks_per_sec = 100000000L;
  unsigned long fraction = tick_count%ticks_per_sec;
  unsigned long long secondsFromJan12014 = tick_count/ticks_per_sec;
  struct tm tm = {0};
  tm.tm_year = 2014 - 1900;
  tm.tm_mday = 1;
  tm.tm_sec = secondsFromJan12014;

  if (mktime(&tm) == (time_t)(-1)) Handle_Failure();
  printf("%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03lu\n",
      tm.tm_year+1900, tm.tm_mon+1, tm.tm_mday,
      tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec,
      fraction/10000);
}
```

Comment: @wallyk  OP can certainly adjust the date/time delimiters as needed.  Maybe since OP is from Brazil, code should use [Date and time notation in Brazil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Brazil)?

Comment: @wallyk I was delimiting per what I thought OP would be most familiar.  Agree ISO 8601 is best to use.  The format would look something like `"%4d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d.%03luZ"`.

Comment: @chux your solution worked! The only problem is that I think `ticks_per_sec` was defined wrongly (1 sec = 10e8 tick counts; testing your solution I got 1 sec from 10e7 tick counts)

Comment: @Momergil Hmmmm  Your "increases 1 each 10 nanoseconds" implies to me 10.0E+07 or `100000000L` ticks per second.  OTOH "increases 1 each 1 nanosecond" implies to me 10.0E+08 ticks per second.

Comment: @chux well 1 nanoseconds corresponds to 10 ^ -9 seconds, so 10 nanoseconds would be 10 ^ -8, so the value there should be, as I put in my final code, `10e8L`. :)

Comment: @Momergil  `10e8` is `10 ^ +9`. `1.0e8` is `10 ^ +8`.

Comment: @chux yeah, you're right :) I confused myself with the "e" notation :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, converting nanoseconds to seconds are trivial.
Second, adding the right number of seconds since the right epoch 1970-01-01 you will have to know how many seconds there were from the epoch UTC 2014-01-01 00:00:00. The date command at the Linux prompt will tell you this:

`date -u -d "2014-01-01 00:00" +%s
1388534400`

So you will simply have to do something like:

time_t current = 1388534400+my_10_nano_time_function()/100000000;

Once you have your correct time_t value you can use all functions like localtime, gmtime and strftime.

However, as time_t is in seconds you will have to calculates the milliseconds yourself,
something like:

`(my_10_nano_time_function()%/100000000)/100000`

Comment: Well what about all this considering not 1970, but 2014? That's a significant part of my problem (it makes using the methods from `time.h` far less trivial).

Comment: That is why you have to add 1388534400 seconds. 2014 january the first is 1388534400 seconds after 1970 january the first.